# Convert SQL Query with Subquery to Drift notations

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, subquery, drift

How to convert this SQL query to Drift syntax without using custom query?

```
SELECT t.*, a."end" 
FROM trackers as t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tracker, MAX(activities."end") as latest_activity_date 
    FROM activities
    GROUP BY tracker
) AS subquery ON t.id = subquery.tracker
LEFT JOIN activities AS a ON subquery.tracker = a.tracker
AND subquery.latest_activity_date = a."end"
ORDER BY a."end";
```

```
(select(trackers).join([
  leftOuterJoin(activities, activities.tracker.equalsExp(trackers.id)),
])
  .get()
  .then((rows) => rows
    .map((row) => TrackerWithLatestActivity(
      row.readTable(trackers), 
      row.readTable(activities)))
    .toList());
```

Where should I put the subquery statement?

Comment: I don't know anything about Drift. You could write your derived table as a scalar subquery in case that's useful.

Comment: You can try using `customSelectQuery` or `customSelectColumn` to use raw query as it is. I dont think there is yet a way to write subqueries in drift.